# Trying to move GIT Project from IntelliJ IDEA to Eclipse with EGit?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea, egit

My firm is making me move back to Eclipse and I am trying to move GIT Project from IntelliJ IDEA to Eclipse with EGit?. The issue I am having is that I access my project from the command line with the following command:

```
git clone git@git:common.git
```

That's how I clone it and then I just work in IntelliJ without a issue, In Eclipse with EGit I am getting the following screen and every setting I am trying down work

[image]

Can someone please tell me based on the command line what options I should be using.. thanks

Comment: You can still checkout via command line and use the import existing project option with Eclipse. This way you can separate management of the git repo and the IDE you use (in case things change again)

Comment: I feel sorry for you that you are forced to use eclipse. Every developer should have the choice to select the IDE that suits them best.

Comment: thanks... I know IntelliJ is the best but firm will not pay for it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always had problems cloning via EGit.  Here's what works for me:

1. Clone via the command-line as usual.
2. Create or import your project into an Eclipse workspace.
3. Right-click the project in the Navigator or Package Explorer.
4. Team > Share Project > Git > Next.
5. Since there will already be .git repo there, select 'Use or create repo in parent...".
6. Finish.  Give it a few seconds and you should see your project files decorated with Git repo information.